# Какой технологический стек использовать для построения видеочата?

Tags: c#, asp.net, веб-программирование

Собираюсь писать видеочат для случайных пользователей, наподобие чат-рулетки. Опыта в постороении подобного рода систем нет. Решил, что точно серверная часть будет написана на asp.net . Возникает вопрос  , какие лучше использовать технологии/протоколы  и какие могут быть подводные камни?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ  будет очень краткий, но надеюсь полезный или познавательный хотя в качестве расширения знаний о технологиях:
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC